# Рассылка сообщений с сохранением форматирования / Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, sendmessage

Я создал два уровня доступа в телеграмм боте. Администратор и пользователь. Администратор имеет возможность рассылать своё сообщение всем пользователям.
Проблем с рассылкой от админа нет через команду `bot.send_message(chat.id, message.text)`.
Но я хочу рассылать сообщение с сохранением форматирования.
`message.text` хранит только текст. А в самом `message` есть информация и о форматировании.

Если администратор написал сообщение:
**всем привет**, то приходит сообщение: всем привет...

```
def message_send_all(message):
    users = newsletter.message_all(connection, 1)
    for user in users:
        try:
            bot.send_message(int(user[0]), message)
            print(int(user[0]))
        except:()
    bot.reply_to(message.chat.id, 'Отправка прервана', reply_markup=markup_start)
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

[message.entities[0].type](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#working-with-entities)

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def ft(message):
    print(message.entities[0].type)
    formatting = {'bold': '*{}*', 'italic': '_{}_', 'underline': '__{}__', 'strikethrough': '~{}~'}
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, formatting[message.entities[0].type].format(message.text), parse_mode='Markdown')
```

UPD:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def ft(message):
    formatting = {'bold': '*{}* ', 'italic': '_{}_ ', 'underline': '__{}__ ', 'strikethrough': '~{}~ '}
    msg = ''
    for i in range(0, len(message.entities)):
        msg = msg + formatting[message.entities[i].type].format(message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[i])

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Comment: Спасибо! А если сообщение будет иметь несколько форматов. Допустим: *привет* **всем**!

Comment: Если ответ является решением вопроса, пожалуйста отметьте его таковым. Это поможет другим пользователям.

на счёт нескольких стилей сейчас подумаю

Comment: обновил свой ответ

Comment: Не работает. Отправляет только первый заголовок и все.
**Заголовок**
Текст
**Глава1** Текст
**Глава2** Текст

Comment: Смотрите какая ошибка, принтуйте шаги. Я проверял на предоставленном примере: _привет_ **всем**

Comment: [Чат пользователя скрин](http://prntscr.com/115mi11) и
[Чат админа скрин](http://prntscr.com/115mj12)

Comment: Добавьте обработку переноса строки

Comment: Violet, можете помочь это сделать. пожалуйста? Спасибо

Comment: @HairLess уточните что именно требуется? Сообщение **XLM/BTC`/n`Цели:** 4500 4600 после сплита хоть и имеет два индекса, но `[1]` не содержит `entities.type` несмотря на форматирование слова Цели. Вы можете это увидеть распечатав `message`.

Comment: Требуется пересылать с сохранением формированием любое сообщение. Форматы могут быть перемещены или быть не на всем тексте.