# Telegram бот на Python гиперссылка в тексте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

пытаюсь сделать, чтобы когда пользователь присылал картинку/и+текст (могут быть жирными слова, с гиперрсылкой) +кнопка (либо же просто присылал фото/ки+текст, текст+фото/ки), бот отправлял ему обратно его же фото/ки+текст+кнопки, но проблема в том, что я написал код криво, и текст отправляется не как исходный (без гиперрсылок, не жирный).

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
        def process_photo(message):
            # проверяем, что у картинки есть подпись (текст)
            if message.caption:
                # получаем url картинки и текст сообщения
                image_url = message.photo[-1].file_id
                text = message.caption
                # отправляем сообщение с картинкой и предлагаем пользователю добавить кнопку
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Вы отправили картинку с текстом\n"
                                                    f"{text}\n""\nВведите URL-адрес для кнопки:", parse_mode="HTML")
                # ждем ответа пользователя с URL-адресом кнопки - .format(text)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(message, lambda msg: add_button_to_message(msg, image_url, text))
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                                    "Картинка должна быть с подписью (текстом). Попробуйте еще раз.")

        # функция для добавления кнопки к сообщению с картинкой
        def add_button_to_message(message, image_url, text):
            # получаем URL-адрес кнопки из сообщения пользователя
            button_url = message.text
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Вы отправили картинку:\n{text}\n\nВведите текст для кнопки")
            # ждем ответа пользователя с URL-адресом кнопки
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, lambda msg: add_button_to_massege_text(msg, image_url, text))

            def add_button_to_massege_text(message, image_url, text):
                mmmm = message.text
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=True)
                link_keyboard22 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=mmmm, url=button_url)
                markup.add(link_keyboard22)
                # отправляем сообщение с картинкой и кнопкой пользователю
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, image_url, reply_markup=markup, caption=text, parse_mode="HTML")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="вот.")
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266498/234134